# PHP/Ajax/jquery action not working after pagination click

Tags: jquery, element

I have a single php page that loads a table with pagination using jquery/ajax. I am unable to get the rows to redirect to a different page once any page in the pagination is clicked (other than the initial page)

Here is simplified code of my generated html for the table. I know the html is generated correctly each time pagination page is changed.

```
<tr class="table-row" data-myredirect="http://example.com/page">
<td>blah blah</td>
</tr>
```

Upon success of loading the table data (only run once after user runs a query), i run the following (simplified):

```
success:function(result){
         //display table data (not shown)
$(".table-row").click(function() {
         //redirect
        window.document.location = $(this).data("myredirect");
    });
}
```

When user selects a different page from the pagination links, the following is run:

```
//executes code below when user click on pagination links
    $("#results").on( "click", ".pagination a", function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".loading-div").show(); //show loading element
        var page = $(this).attr("data-page"); //get page number from link
        $("#results").load("test.php",{"page":page, "myparam":searchItemOne}, function(){ //get content from PHP page
            $(".loading-div").hide(); //once done, hide loading element
            //fixes scrolling up bug
            $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#results").offset().top
     }, 0);
        });

    });
```

What might be causing the action to no longer work once I navigate to the next pagination page? I can include more code upon request.

Comment: Can you provide a somewhat more complete (but still minimal) example of the problem?  I *suspect* that this is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements  But it's hard to know for certain with the incomplete segments posted.

Comment: Do you care about the PHP or only the javascript type code?

Comment: If the problem is client-side, then the client-side code seems the appropriate thing to examine.

Comment: You're right. As a simple fix, I added the existing:

$(".table-row").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("myredirect");
    });

to the code that runs once each pagination link is clicked. It fixed the issue. Can you think of anything wrong with this fix?

Comment: Well, if you're adding click handlers on an AJAX callback, then chances are you can just add a single top-level handler once instead.  The linked question on the comment above demonstrates that.  There wouldn't really be an observed difference, but it would be better style and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it's because your `.table-row` is rendered after the javascript code ( after you load the html via AJAX the second time) so the redirection code doesn't know the new `table-row` . 
try to put the redirection code

```
$(".table-row").click(function() {
         //redirect
        window.document.location = $(this).data("myredirect");
    });
```

in your `php` file so it reloads with the new html 
.

Answer (score 0):

[Taki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328218/taki) doesn't provide the solution but a guide.

To resolve the problem, I moved the `$('#results').DataTable();` to the end of my javascripts, after defining the `$(".table-row").click()` event. Now all my pages do fire the embedded funtions.